# Converting GOPATH repo with multiple programs into GO modules

Tags: go, go-modules

We have an older git repository that was uses the older GOPATH structure.  That repository includes code for multiple utilities, each with its own main.go.  Additionally, it contains a "common" folder with multiple subfolders, each with various shared bits functionality.  The result is something like this:

```
progOne\main.go (and other code, some in subfolders)
progTwo\main.go (and other code, some in subfolders)
progThree\main.go (and other code, some in subfolders)
common\net\ (go files, but no main)
common\colors\ (go files, but no main)
common\resources\ (go files, but no main)
```

In converting this to go modules, can I leave all of this in one git repo that is used to produce muliple executibles?  If yes, which of the subfolders need to include a go.mod file?

EDIT: Thanks to @colm.anseo for his thorough response.  This is probably a separate question, but since it is closely related, I'll ask it here.

Once I created a go.mod file in the root of the repo as suggested, I opened the root folder in VSCode.  I'd like to debug "ProgOne", so I set up a launch configuration like this:

```
{
   "name": "Launch Package",
   "type": "go",
   "request": "launch",
   "mode": "debug",
   "program": "${workspaceFolder}/progOne/main.go",
   "buildFlags": ""
}
```

But when I attempt to launch the debugger, the build fails:

```
Starting: /Users/me/dev/go/bin/dlv dap --check-go-version=false --listen=127.0.0.1:58867 --log-dest=3 from /Users/me/dev/convoy/myRepo/progOne
DAP server listening at: 127.0.0.1:58867
Build Error: go build -o /Users/me/dev/convoy/myRepo/progOne/__debug_bin -gcflags all=-N -l ./main.go
main.go:20:2: no required module provides package git.acme.com/myRepo/common/colors; to add it:
    go get git.acme.com/myRepo/common/colors
(exit status 1)
```

I ran both "go mod tidy" and "go get git.acme.com/myRepo/common/colors", but that didn't fix it.  I wouldn't expect either of those to be necessary, since the module in question is part of this repository.

What do I need to do to get that import working?

Comment: None of the subdirectories *need* to have a go.mod, and in fact probably shouldn't have unless you have a good reason to version the programs independently from one another.

Comment: If these are all part of one project, and developed together, you should probably have a single `go.mod`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I leave all of this in one git repo that is used to produce muliple executibles?

Yes.

> If yes, which of the subfolders need to include a go.mod file?

As @Peter noted - only the ones you need to version.

Just `go mod init` if you are unsure - and provide a module path if the one that is generated is not correct.

---

Bonus suggestion, tag your individual directories via git tags if you are versioning that directory. You can do this for packages (non-main) directories or executable (main) packages.

This will allow user to install specific versions of your executables if need be.

Example git tags for the executable(s):

```
progOne/v0.1.0
progTwo/v0.2.5
progThree/v0.3.4
```

and a user could install a specific version like so:

```
go install github.com/me/myrepo/progOne@v0.1.0
```

or use `@latest` to grab the latest version.

And if the packages need specific version of your dependency packages, tag them like so:

```
common/net/v0.1.2
common/colors/v0.3.5
common/resources/v0.5.9
```

for each executable that depends on these, you would perform a `go get` with the desired version (which will in turn update `go.mod`)

As you can see from above the tag should match the directory name - and then end with a [SemVer](https://semver.org/).

For information on module tagging see the official blog post [Publishing Go Modules](https://go.dev/blog/publishing-go-modules)

Comment: Thanks for your thorough response.  This is what I was hoping to accomplish and the git tagging is also valuable information.  

One of the guys in my team discovered this example in the go-modules-by-example repository, which provides a different alternative.  I don't really understand what the advantages and disadvantaged of each are.

Comment: You can start with a single `go.mod` at the top level just to get your project converted to Go modules. Then you can decide how much churn each of the 6 components may have. If a dependent packages can have non-breaking future e.g. new functions needed by `progOne` but not by `ProgTwo` - then nothing needs to be done. However if you need to make some breaking changes and need to stage an update - then you will need to support multiple versions of that package.  This is where go module versioning shines, and you can `go.mod` that package and tag the newer commit with the newer version.